# Displaying folder name in a specific format using Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, directory, mkdir

I am a Create Customer form with a button and the following textboxes: txtCustomerID, txtFirstName, txtLastName, txtPhone, txtEmail. When I click the button, the information typed in the textboxes are inserted into [Customer] table and creates a folder based on the value of txtCustomerID, txtFirstName, and txtLastName. For example, if..

txtCustomerID: *100*

txtFirstName: *Ron*

txtLastName: *Smith*

I want the folder name to display "**100 - Ron Smith**", but I can't find a solution to do that.

Below is the code that I used and it works perfectly, I just can't get it to the way I want to display the folder name.

```html
Private Sub btnCreate_Click()
    DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO [Customer] (CustomerID, FirstName, LastName, Phone, Email) VALUES ('" & Me.txtCustomerID & "', '" & Me.txtFirstName & "', '" & Me.txtLastName & "', '" & Me.txtPhone & "', '" & Me.txtEmail & "')"

    MkDir ("C:\Users\Desktop\" & txtCustomerID.Value & txtFirstName.Value & txtLastName.Value)
End Sub
```

Any help or suggestion would be great. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MkDir ("C:\Users\Desktop\" & txtCustomerID.Value & " - " & txtFirstName.Value & " " &  txtLastName.Value)
```

will add the dash and spaces that you want.

Answer (score 1):

Should be as simple as putting in spaces.....

```
Private Sub btnCreate_Click()
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO [Customer] (CustomerID, FirstName, LastName, Phone, Email) VALUES ('" & Me.txtCustomerID & "', '" & Me.txtFirstName & "', '" & Me.txtLastName & "', '" & Me.txtPhone & "', '" & Me.txtEmail & "')"

MkDir ("C:\Users\Desktop\" & txtCustomerID.Value & " - " & txtFirstName.Value & " " & txtLastName.Value)
End Sub
```